# Seaborn heatmap not showing columns converted from string to numerical

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, heatmap, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with 12 columns. When plotting with seaborn's heatmap, only 9 columns are shown. Three of them ('card','owner','selfemp') are missing.

[image: heatmap]

The code I used for plotting is:

```
sns.heatmap(data.corr(),xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

where `data` is my dataframe's name and those 3 columns are missing were converted to numeric from string using following code:

```
data.selfemp[data.selfemp == 'yes'] = 1
data.selfemp[data.selfemp == 'no'] = 0

data.card[data.card == 'yes'] = 1
data.card[data.card == 'no'] = 0

data.owner[data.owner == 'yes'] = 1
data.owner[data.owner == 'no'] = 0
```

I want the heatmap to correlate between all columns since **'card'** is my outcome attribute.

Comment: can you print sample data in dataframe before you run the heatmap? I suspect the 3 columns are not numeric. THanks

Comment: Please refer to [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You should set card, owner, selfemp columns types to `int64`.

Changing values of rows is not enough to let pandas understand that this column is now numeric. After you convert those columns to numeric types, pandas's `corr()` method will know to take them into account. Notice that seaborn's heatmap has nothing to do with that: the problem is with what columns `data.corr()` consider.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2012, 2011, 2013, 2014], "card":["yes", "yes", "no", "yes"], "some_col":[1,0,1,0]})
df.loc[df.card == 'yes', "card"] = 1
df.loc[df.card == 'no', "card"] = 0
df["card"] = df["card"].astype('int64')
```

This toy example demonstrate how to properly change value of columns, and also change column's type.
Also take note that I used `df.loc`, as you don't want to assign it to a copy (which gives a warning the way you did). There is a better way of course to change values, using a dictionary, but it's irrelevant for now.

The last line tell pandas that "card" column is now of type "int64". With it, df.corr() works properly. Without it, pandas think "card" column is of type "object", so it ignores it when computing correlation.